# Checkbox Using Last Value As First Array

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Good Day guys, Please issue on how best to manage my checkbox value in a for loop.
first in the form below, people are only to check the **Male** checkbox if they are male and leave it if the are female.
Now my issue is, if the last checkbox is checked, automatically it means only the value of that particular checkbox is set. this makes my php loop to assign it to the first looping data/result.
Please how can i rectify this. Thanks in Advance

```
<form method="Post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[]" >
    <input type="text" name="name[]" >

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" >

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" >

</form>
<?php

$data ="";

    for ($x=0; $x < sizeof($_POST['name']); $x++) {

    $gender = (isset($_POST['male']) ? "Male" : "Female");

    $data .=$_POST['name'][$x].'</br>';

    $data .=$gender.'</br>';

    };

    echo $data;

?>
```

supposing the last checkbox in the form was checked, the above code outputs,

```
**Esther** Male
**John** Female
**Mark** Female
```

Whats happening is its passing the value of the last checked box since it was the only one selected.
please how do i manage this

Answer (score 1):

When browser submits forms it only submits checkboxes that are checked. And if you use name as `male[]` the indexes are assigned by php only to data that has been recieved. Thanks to that the `$_POST` data in your case looks like this:

```php
array( 
    'name' => array(
        0 => 'Esther',
        1 => 'John',
        2 => 'Mark',
    ),
    'male' => array(
        0 => 1
    ),
);
```

If you want your `male` array indexes to match the `name` indexes then you need to define array indexes in the name attribute.

```html
<form method="Post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[0]" >
    <input type="text" name="name[0]" >

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[1]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[1]" >

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[2]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[2]" >
</form>
```

This way even if only checkbox send is the last one, the indexes in array will be kept and the `$_POST` will look like this:

```php
array( 
    'name' => array(
        0 => 'Esther',
        1 => 'John',
        2 => 'Mark',
    ),
    'male' => array(
        2 => 1
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, dont know what would have done without you all. <br> It work fine with a little modification in my php loop too. **Thanks Once Again** I Appreciate

Comment: @SpywaveNoah you should vote up (and pick as right answer) whichever answer you deem correct

Answer (score 0):

You can define the indices of the resulting php array in your html by simply adding the key name between the brackets. (Note that this also works with words, you will end up with an associative array. Do not use quotes in your html.)

```html
<form method="Post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[0]" >
    <input type="text" name="name[0]" >

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[1]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[1]" >

    <input type="checkbox" name="male[2]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[2]" >

</form>
```